# Syntax error in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a syntax error that I can't solve for an hour now:

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ")"

```
with all_comp_prices as 
(
    SELECT distinct 
        m2198.to_product_id AS competitor_product_id,
        h_comp.when_seen,
        h_comp.when_seen / 86400 AS day,
        h_comp.price 
    FROM
        tbl_productmatch_2198 as m2198
        JOIN
        (
        select * from tbl_producthistory_2414 
        union select * from tbl_producthistory_2415
         -- insert union more competitors here
        )
        as h_comp

        ON  h_comp.product_id = m2198.to_product_id 
    WHERE
        h_comp.when_seen >= extract(epoch from (getdate() - INTERVAL '7 DAYS'))
)
select 2198 as customer_site,
TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + lt.day*86400 * INTERVAL '1 second' as date,
sum(if(ap.price is null,1,0)) as no_price_competitors_products_count,
sum(if(ap.price is null,1,0))/1 as ratio_to_total_competitors_products
from
(
    select acp.competitor_product, max(acp.when_seen) latest_time, acp.day from
    all_comp_prices as acp
    group by acp.competitor_product, acp.day
) as lt -- latest times for each product per day
join 
(
    all_comp_prices as ap -- all prices for all times
)
on lt.latest_time=ap.when_seen and lt.competitor_product=ap.competitor_product
group by lt.day
;
```

I tried to run the select statement inside the with closure and it runs as expected.
I suppose the mistake is somewhere under `select 2198 as customer_site,` ...

I go with MySql logic (except the `WITH` closure) so maybe my mistake stems from that.
Anyone?

Comment: Why working with epoch when you could use an ISO date or timestamp? It makes coding and debugging so much easier. Reading the manual also helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the `IF` to `CASE` and the errors never came back:

```
with all_comp_prices as 
(
    SELECT distinct 
        m2198.to_product_id AS competitor_product_id,
        h_comp.when_seen,
        h_comp.when_seen / 86400 AS day,
        h_comp.price 
    FROM
        tbl_productmatch_2198 as m2198
        JOIN
        (
        select * from tbl_producthistory_2414 
        union select * from tbl_producthistory_2415
         -- insert union more competitors here
        )
        as h_comp

        ON  h_comp.product_id = m2198.to_product_id 
    WHERE
        h_comp.when_seen >= extract(epoch from (getdate() - INTERVAL '7 DAYS'))
)
select 2198 as customer_site,
TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + lt.day*86400 * INTERVAL '1 second' as date,
sum(CASE WHEN ap.price is null THEN 1 else 0 END) as no_price_competitors_products_count,
from
(
select acp.competitor_product_id, max(acp.when_seen) latest_time, acp.day from
    all_comp_prices as acp
    group by acp.competitor_product_id, acp.day
) as lt -- latest times for each products per day
join 
all_comp_prices as ap -- all prices for all times
on lt.latest_time=ap.when_seen and lt.competitor_product_id=ap.competitor_product_id
group by date
```

Comment: I work with Amazon Redshift and here is the documentation for it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html

Comment: My fault I did not mention it (edited the question). Thought the syntax is entirely the same since Redshift is based on Postgresql.

Comment: Well the `getdate()` proves it's not _entirely_ the same. Additionally: Redshift is based on a **really** old Postgres version.